# Prompt: Is there a function to check if a prompt is already opened?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Title explains it.
So far, I've tried using variables to help with checking all of this, but it really doesn't help. At all.
I was expecting to find some kind of if(prompt.prompted) or anything like that but there isn't anything.
I'm using this library for prompts: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt

```
var alreadyAsked = 1
function askForMessage() {
  prompt.start();

  if(alreadyAsked = 0) {
    // already asked - true
    return;
  }

  if(alreadyAsked = 1) {
    // already asked - false
    var alreadyAsked = 0
    prompt.get(['Message'], function (err, result) {
        if (err) { return onErr(err); }
        client.channels.cache.get('789978401929822211').send(result.Message);
        var alreadyAsked = 1
      })
  }
}


client.on("message", async message => {
  const args = message.content.slice(0).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const messageReceived = args.join(" ")

  console.log(`\n${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}: ${messageReceived}`)

  askForMessage()
})

function onErr(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had several logical errors.. first being you're starting a new prompt whether or whether not one was already asked.. second being your checks to see if `alreadyAsked` assigns a number instead of checking for a number.. third being you assign a new variable **IN** the scope of your function instead of rewriting the variable you're looking at

Check if the below example works

```
var alreadyAsked=1
function askForMessage() {
  
  if(alreadyAsked == 0) {
    // already asked - true
    return;
  }
  
  if(alreadyAsked == 1) {
    // already asked - false
    prompt.start();
    alreadyAsked = 0
    prompt.get(['Message'], function (err, result) {
        if (err) { return onErr(err); }
        client.channels.cache.get('789978401929822211').send(result.Message);
        var alreadyAsked = 1
      })
  }
}


client.on("message", async message => {
  const args = message.content.slice(0).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const messageReceived = args.join(" ")

  console.log(`\n${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}: ${messageReceived}`)

  askForMessage()
})

function onErr(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Works, but now it doesn't quite ask for a new message.

Comment: @Stefan i forgot to `prompt.start` LOL ty